# PersistenceException: Error with [models.Task] It has not been enhanced but it's superClass

Tags: playframework, ebean

I am working with two databases so while saving the data object in the Table I am getting the following error:

PersistenceException: Error with [models.Task] It has not been enhanced but its superClass [class play.db.ebean.Model] has? (You are not allowed to mix enhancement in a single inheritance hierarchy) marker[play.db.ebean.Model] className[models.Task]

I am using the two Java classes one is Task.class and other is Userdetails.class:

Task.class :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="third")
public class Task extends Model {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String username;

    public static Finder finduser=new Finder<String,Task>(String.class,Task.class);

}
```

And Userdetails.class :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="userdetails")
public class UserDetail extends Model{

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="username")
    private String username;
    @Column(name="itemdetail")
    private String itemname;

    public static Finder finduser=new Finder<String,UserDetail (String.class,UserDetail.class);
}
```

My application.conf file is:

```
db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?characterEncoding=UTF-8"
db.default.user=root
ebean.default="models.UserDetail"
evolutionplugin=disabled

db.secondary.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.secondary.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/secondary?characterEncoding=UTF-8"
db.secondary.user=root
ebean.secondary="models.Task"
```

I have tried some solutions from stackoverflow but still it's not working. Some of them like:

```
1. @MappedSuperclass
2. ebean.dafault=model.*.*
```

Comment: Could you please provide your `model.Task` entities code and anything else that would give more context?

Comment: Hi Donovan Muller I have provided the details kindly check , and let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you [read this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12201228/2408961)?

You did not mention the Play version you are using? 
The following configuration works for me on Play 2.2.3:

```
db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?characterEncoding=UTF-8"
db.default.user=xxx
db.default.password="xxx"
ebean.default="models.UserDetail"

db.secondary.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.secondary.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/secondary?characterEncoding=UTF-8"
db.secondary.user=xxx
db.secondary.password="xxx"
ebean.secondary="models.Task"
```

The following controller code saves your entities (as they are) to the two databases correctly:

```
public static Result index() {
    UserDetail userDetail = new UserDetail();
    userDetail.save();

    Task task = new Task();
    task.save("secondary");
}
```

note that I pass in the server name to the `save()` method for `models.Task`. This tells Ebean which datasource to use when saving.

Why are your entities fields `private` and not `public`? Did you leave out the getters/setters for brevity or is there another reason? I ask because of [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17342384/2408961)